# Infinite loop when calling detectChanges() inside ngAfterViewChecked?

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection, angular-changedetection

I recently reviewed some code where `detectChanges()` is called from `ngAfterViewChecked`. How does that not cause an infinite loop? Shouldn't it trigger another change detection cycle, which will call `ngAfterViewChecked` again? Or does the change detection only apply to the *view*, and therefore `ngAfterViewChecked` will only be called on the child components, not the host component?

Answer (score 0):

You already answered it yourself: If you call `detectChanges()` in a component, the change detection applies only to this view. You could theoretically cause an infinite loop by calling `ApplicationRef.tick()` instead, which triggers change detection on the root, but Angular catches this and throws the error below:
[image]

A good deep-in-the-code overview of change detection is given in [this article](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f).